# Comparing Date from PHP to MYSQL, strtotime not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, mysqli

I have a DATE field on my MySQL table. Let's say the value is 2015-05-05. 
I would like to check if the current time is before or after that.
This is my code:

```
foreach ($row as $row)
{
    $ExpDate = strtotime($row['exp_date']);
    $Today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));


    echo $Today . ' - ' . $ExpDate;
    if ($Today > $ExpDate)
    {
        exit('<M>LicenseExpired<M>');
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's not working. The value of exp without strtotime is 2015-05-05. It I add the strtotime, the value becomes an empty string.

How am I able to solve this problem or what would be a good way to compare dates in PHP?

Comment: Are you sure the value in DB is Y-m-d ? did you var dump it to make sure its whats expected?

Comment: What data type is exp_date?

Comment: WHY do you use strtotime at all?

Comment: what is result of this $row['exp_date'] ? say correctly..

Comment: How are you receiving the date? It would be much simpler to let MySQL or your Database engine tell you if the date has passed or not.

Comment: the result of $row['exp_date'] is 2015-05-05. exp_date is DATE. not datetime, just DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing dates in MySQL there is no reason to take the extra step and use `string_to_time()`. The below example should work just fine. The format of [MySQL DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) is designed in such a way that comparisons of this nature work naturally without any extra steps needed.

```
foreach ($row as $row)
{
    $ExpDate = $row['exp_date'];
    $Today = date("Y-m-d");


    echo $Today . ' - ' . $ExpDate;
    if ($Today > $ExpDate)
    {
        exit('<M>LicenseExpired<M>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this have worked perfectly. I should of took a closer look at date() method rather than strtotime.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach ($row as $row)
{   
$ExpDate = new DateTime($row['exp_date']);
$Today = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$interval = $ExpDate->diff($Today);
   //echo $interval->format('%R%a days');  <--- to diffenernce by days.

   if ($interval > 0)
{
    exit('<M>LicenseExpired<M>');
}
}
```